# Первое слово в input не кликабельно. Что может быть?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

В input написано "Ваше имя" и при клике на "Ваше" ничего не происходит. 
Что может быть?

```css
.text-form {
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
.input-text {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-color: #B4B4B4;
  color: #000;
  padding-right: 100px;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<form class="form" action="form.php" method="POST">
  <p class="text-form">Получите бесплатный<br> аудит от меня уже сегодня</p>
  <input type="text" class="input-text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя"><br>
  <input type="text" class="input-text input-text_bottom input-phone" name="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон" required><br>
</form>
```

Comment: напишите используемый код, чтобы можно было дать нормальный ответ

Comment: `<form class="form" action="form.php" method="POST">
<p class="text-form">Получите бесплатный<br> аудит от меня уже сегодня</p>
<input type="text" class="input-text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя"><br>
<input type="text" class="input-text input-text_bottom input-phone" name="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон" required><br><div>`

Comment: `.text-form {
 margin-bottom: -2px;
 font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.input-text {
 border-top: none;
 border-left: none;
 border-right: none;
 border-color: #B4B4B4;
 color: #000;
 padding-right: 100px;
 background: transparent;
}
`

Comment: Извините, не знаю как сделать правильно код

Comment: @ДаниилДаниил Редактируете вопрос, а в редакторе с верху есть кнопка что бы добавить рабочий код.

Comment: В приведенном примере все работает. Возможно у вас поверх инпута лежит другой элемент, поэтому клик происходит на нем

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в инструментах разработчика навести курсор на нужную зону, если выделится не input, то смотрите, что не так со стилями. Или просто добавьте position: relative и z-index.

Comment: Спасибо. блок с absolute захаел на верх.